# MySQL 5.7 full outer join

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Table 1 and sample data:-

```
CREATE TABLE student_p (
    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    S_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Points DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    P_date DATE NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO student_p VALUES
    (50055, 3330, 45, '2023-11-30'),
    (50056,  332, 43, '2013-10-31'),
    (50057, 3330, 22, '2013-10-30');
```

Table 2 and sample data: -

```
CREATE TABLE student_act (
    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    s_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    VIDEO_SCORE DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    EXERCISESCORE DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    DS INT NOT NULL,
    A_date DATE NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO student_act VALUES
    (2333, 233, 22.43,  233.4455, 23, '2023-11-30'),
    (2334, 235, 24.566,      232, 34, '2023-10-31'),
    ( 322, 678, 23,           45, 23, '2022-10-30'),
    ( 433,  45, 23,           23, 43, '2022-10-01');
```

Only ids in both table can't be duplicate rest all data can be duplicate.

student_p table: -

| ID | S_id | Points | P_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50055 | 3330 | 45 | 2023-11-30 |
| 50056 | 332 | 43 | 2013-10-31 |
| 50057 | 3330 | 22 | 2013-10-30 |

student_act table: -

| ID | s_id | VIDEO_SCORE | Lesson_score | DS | A_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2333 | 233 | 22.43 | 233.4455 | 23 | 2023-11-30 |
| 2334 | 235 | 24.566 | 232 | 34 | 2023-10-31 |
| 322 | 678 | 23 | 45 | 23 | 2022-10-30 |
| 433 | 45 | 23 | 23 | 43 | 2022-10-01 |

desired result: -

| year | month | points | VIDEO_SCORE | Lesson_score | DS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 11 | 45 | 22.43 | 233.4455 | 23 |
| 2023 | 10 | null | 24.566 | 232 | 34 |
| 2022 | 10 | null | 46 | 68 | 66 |
| 2013 | 10 | 65 | null | null | null |

Comment: Please add table definitions as text and an explain.

Comment: Mysql does not have full join but searching for  mysql full join will give you alternatives.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second query you are restricting the result set by the year. If that is what you want to do, you should do it based on the date, not a function on the date, as that is [non-sargable](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/12/the-two-ways-to-fix-non-sargable-queries/). This will then be able to use the index suggested by Hossam. Putting it (overly) simplistically, the `HAVING` clause is applied after doing all the work, whereas the `WHERE` clause reduces the amount of work being done:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(msa.DATE) AS Year,
  MONTH(msa.DATE) AS Month,
  SUM(msk.POINT) AS Ps,
  SUM(msa.VIDEO_SCORE) AS Video,
  SUM(msa.EXERCISESCORE) AS Lessons,
  SUM(msa.DS) AS DS
FROM student_p msk
RIGHT JOIN student_act msa ON msk.DATE = msa.DATE
WHERE msa.DATE >= MAKEDATE(2023, 1) AND msa.DATE < MAKEDATE(2024, 1)
GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`;
```

[MAKEDATE(year,dayofyear)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_makedate)

> Returns a date, given year and day-of-year values. dayofyear must be greater than 0 or the result is NULL.

---

In one of your comments you stated that you wanted a `full join`, which MySQL does not have but you can achieve the same with a `(LEFT|RIGHT) JOIN` `UNION`ed to another `(LEFT|RIGHT) JOIN`.

```
WITH st (`Year`, `Month`, `Ps`) AS (
    SELECT
        YEAR(`P_date`) AS `Year`,
        MONTH(`P_date`) AS `Month`,
        SUM(`Points`)
    FROM `student_p`
    -- WHERE `P_date` >= MAKEDATE(2023, 1) AND `P_date` < MAKEDATE(2024, 1)
    GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`
),
act (`Year`, `Month`, `Video`, `Lessons`, `DS`) AS (
    SELECT
        YEAR(`A_date`) AS `Year`,
        MONTH(`A_date`) AS `Month`,
        SUM(`VIDEO_SCORE`) AS `Video`,
        SUM(`EXERCISESCORE`) AS `Lessons`,
        SUM(`DS`) AS `DS`
    FROM student_act
    -- WHERE A_date >= MAKEDATE(2023, 1) AND DATE < MAKEDATE(2024, 1)
    GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`
)
SELECT
    `Year`,
    `Month`,
    SUM(`Ps`) AS `Ps`,
    SUM(`Video`) AS `Video`,
    SUM(`Lessons`) AS `Lessons`,
    SUM(`DS`) AS `DS`
FROM (
    SELECT `act`.`Year`, `act`.`Month`, `Ps`, `Video`, `Lessons`, `DS`
    FROM `st`
    RIGHT JOIN `act` ON `st`.`Year` = `act`.`Year` AND `st`.`Month` = `act`.`Month`

    UNION ALL

    SELECT `st`.`Year`, `st`.`Month`, `Ps`, `Video`, `Lessons`, `DS`
    FROM `st`
    LEFT JOIN `act` ON `st`.`Year` = `act`.`Year` AND `st`.`Month` = `act`.`Month`
    WHERE `act`.`Year` IS NULL
) t
GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`
ORDER BY `Year` DESC, `Month` DESC;
```

Output:

| Year | Month | Ps | Video | Lessons | DS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 11 | 45 | 22.43 | 233.4455 | 23 |
| 2023 | 10 | NULL | 24.566 | 232 | 34 |
| 2022 | 10 | NULL | 46 | 68 | 66 |
| 2013 | 10 | 65 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

The two CTEs do the aggregation. I left the `WHERE` clauses in but commented out.

The first query in the `UNION` is your current `RIGHT JOIN` retrieving all records from the right hand table, whether or not they have an associated row in the left hand table. The second query then gets all the rows from the left hand table which do not have an associated row in the right hand side.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RJPUDweB) with invalid dates and duplicate PK values tweaked.

---

For MySQL 5.7 you will have to repeat the subqueries within your main query, as CTEs are not available to you:

```
SELECT
    `Year`,
    `Month`,
    SUM(`Ps`) AS `Ps`,
    SUM(`Video`) AS `Video`,
    SUM(`Lessons`) AS `Lessons`,
    SUM(`DS`) AS `DS`
FROM (
    SELECT `act`.`Year`, `act`.`Month`, `Ps`, `Video`, `Lessons`, `DS`
    FROM (
        SELECT
            YEAR(`P_date`) AS `Year`,
            MONTH(`P_date`) AS `Month`,
            SUM(`Points`) AS `Ps`
        FROM `student_p`
        -- WHERE `P_date` >= MAKEDATE(2023, 1) AND `P_date` < MAKEDATE(2024, 1)
        GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`
    ) `st`
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT
            YEAR(`A_date`) AS `Year`,
            MONTH(`A_date`) AS `Month`,
            SUM(`VIDEO_SCORE`) AS `Video`,
            SUM(`EXERCISESCORE`) AS `Lessons`,
            SUM(`DS`) AS `DS`
        FROM student_act
        -- WHERE A_date >= MAKEDATE(2023, 1) AND DATE < MAKEDATE(2024, 1)
        GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`
    ) `act` ON `st`.`Year` = `act`.`Year` AND `st`.`Month` = `act`.`Month`

    UNION ALL

    SELECT `st`.`Year`, `st`.`Month`, `Ps`, `Video`, `Lessons`, `DS`
    FROM (
        SELECT
            YEAR(`P_date`) AS `Year`,
            MONTH(`P_date`) AS `Month`,
            SUM(`Points`) AS `Ps`
        FROM `student_p`
        -- WHERE `P_date` >= MAKEDATE(2023, 1) AND `P_date` < MAKEDATE(2024, 1)
        GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`
    ) `st`
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            YEAR(`A_date`) AS `Year`,
            MONTH(`A_date`) AS `Month`,
            SUM(`VIDEO_SCORE`) AS `Video`,
            SUM(`EXERCISESCORE`) AS `Lessons`,
            SUM(`DS`) AS `DS`
        FROM student_act
        -- WHERE A_date >= MAKEDATE(2023, 1) AND DATE < MAKEDATE(2024, 1)
        GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`
    ) `act` ON `st`.`Year` = `act`.`Year` AND `st`.`Month` = `act`.`Month`
    WHERE `act`.`Year` IS NULL
) t
GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`
ORDER BY `Year` DESC, `Month` DESC;
```

Output:

| Year | Month | Ps | Video | Lessons | DS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 11 | 45 | 22.43 | 233.4455 | 23 |
| 2023 | 10 | NULL | 24.566 | 232 | 34 |
| 2022 | 10 | NULL | 46 | 68 | 66 |
| 2013 | 10 | 65 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tYomK6OA)

Is this what you are looking for?

The second query in the `UNION` could be replaced with:

```
    SELECT
        YEAR(`P_date`) AS `Year`,
        MONTH(`P_date`) AS `Month`,
        SUM(`Points`) AS `Ps`,
        NULL AS `Video`,
        NULL AS `Lessons`,
        NULL AS `DS`
    FROM `student_p`
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM student_act
        WHERE A_date BETWEEN student_p.P_date - INTERVAL (DAY(student_p.P_date) - 1) DAY
                         AND LAST_DAY(student_p.P_date)
    )
    -- AND `P_date` >= MAKEDATE(2023, 1) AND `P_date` < MAKEDATE(2024, 1)
    GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`
```

You'll have to experiment with these query variations and your real data to see what works best. You should throw O. Jones' suggestion into the mix too, to see if it improves the performance of the aggregate queries.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qpXO7qcx)

If you have performance issues with this query, please update your question including the EXPLAIN output for the full query, and for the two aggregation subqueries.

Comment: this helps a lot for 5.7 version thank you so much

Comment: the query works fine can just explain " WHERE `act`.`Year` IS NULL" why are we using this.

Comment: This is because the rows with values on both sides of the join are already returned in the first query. That anti-join could be replaced with `NOT EXISTS` which may perform slightly better.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you can try to [index](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-index-overview-and-strategy/) your DATE field on the student_act table.
Indexing helps the SQL engine to find records based on that field faster.

MySql:

```
ALTER TABLE `student_act` ADD INDEX `date_index` (`DATE`)
```

Indexing optimises the lookup process in SQL engines, usually very effective if the query matches records based on MULTIPLE fields, or like in your example, the matched field is non-numeric.

Also, try to rename your field to something different than DATE, as it is a reserved word in some SQL engines.

Comment: thank you so much this helps, also changed the date column

Comment: hey man, no worries, please upvote and mark as correct answer <3

Comment: i want to use full join on this query but getting an error can you help?
SELECT YEAR(msa.DATE) AS Year, MONTH(msa.DATE) AS Month,  SUM(msk.POINT) AS Ps, SUM(msa.VIDEO_SCORE) AS Video, SUM(msa.EXERCISESCORE) AS Lessons, SUM(msa.DS) AS DS FROM student_p msk full JOIN student_act msa ON msk.id= msa.id GROUP BY  YEAR(msa.DATE),MONTH(msa.DATE)

Getting syntax error

Comment: Remove "FULL" from query

Comment: only "JOIN" refer to inner not full join?

Comment: here's a good explanation: https://www.devart.com/white-papers-landing/types-of-joins-in-mysql.html#:~:text=MySQL%20supports%20the%20following%20JOIN,join%20more%20than%20two%20tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
SELECT
  YEAR(msa.DATE) AS Year,
  MONTH(msa.DATE) AS Month,
  SUM(msk.POINT) AS Ps,
  SUM(msa.VIDEO_SCORE) AS Video,
  SUM(msa.EXERCISESCORE) AS Lessons,
  SUM(msa.DS) AS DS
FROM student_p msk
RIGHT JOIN student_act msa ON msk.DATE = msa.DATE
WHERE msa.DATE between '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-12-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY MONTH(msa.DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the [YEAR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) and [MONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) functions, try grouping by [LAST_DAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day). It gives you the last day of the month containing any [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP.

Like this:

```sql
SELECT
  LAST_DAY(msa.DATE) AS MonthEnding,
  SUM(msk.POINT) AS Ps,
  SUM(msa.VIDEO_SCORE) AS Video,
  SUM(msa.EXERCISESCORE) AS Lessons,
  SUM(msa.DS) AS DS
FROM student_p msk
RIGHT JOIN student_act msa ON msk.DATE = msa.DATE
WHERE msa.DATE >= MAKEDATE(2023, 1) AND msa.DATE < MAKEDATE(2024, 1)
GROUP BY LAST_DAY(msa.DATE);
```

Create a [covering index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index) on `student_p(date, POINT)` and another on `student_act(DATE, VIDEO_SCORE, EXERCISES_SCORE, DS)`.

That form of the query and those indexes will help a lot.